# how to show events link in .net calendar control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to develop a calendar that could show events link on it. The events will have datetime field used to locate date on calendar and it also have a link field to make hyperlink on calendar. If don't use 3rd party software, how to develop such a calendar? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in 3rd party commercial ASP.NET controls where the work is already done for you, check out these solutions (in no particular order):

- [ComponentOne Scheduler](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ScheduleASPNET/)
- [Infragistics WebSchedule](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webschedule.aspx#Overview)
- [Telerik Scheduler](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/scheduler.aspx)
- [ComponentArt Scheduler](http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/scheduler/features/core_features/WebForm1.aspx)
- [DevExpress ASPxScheduler](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Scheduler/)

If none of those are suitable or if you're really looking for something free or open source, check out the answers to the question [What is a good (cheap/free) calendar/schedule control for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254989/what-is-a-good-cheap-free-calendar-schedule-control-for-asp-net)